# How to call the Azure REST API inside of .Net Core 6 API

Tags: .net, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rest-api

I have a **service principal** which has access to all tenants and its resources in my organization.
The `client_id client_secret and tenant_id` are used in a `.Net Core 6 API` and following function is used to get an access token of that service principal:

```
public string getAccessToken(string tenantID)
        {
            var _config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
            var scopes = new string[] { _config["Azure:vm-executer:scope"]! };

            var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
             .Create(_config["Azure:vm-executer:client_id"])
             .WithTenantId(tenantID)
             .WithClientSecret(_config["Azure:vm-executer:client_secret"])
             .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/token")
             .Build();

            var result = confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            return result.Result.AccessToken;
        }
```

I used that access token *successfully* to make requests to the **Azure REST API** to

1. list subscriptions with `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01`
2. list virtual machines with `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionID}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2022-11-01`

> I did this all in postman and it works really well!

However, now I want to do from inside my .Net 6 API.

**My goal** is to specifically return the response postman gave me for a specific request.
So for example when I want to list the subscriptions, then it should have the same response from postman like this:
[image: Subscription response]

So far I have implemented this function using the RestClient but I'm stuck and am in need for help.

```
public SubscriptionResource getSubscriptionID(string accessToken)
        {
            var uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01";
            var client = new RestClient();
            var request = new RestRequest(uri, Method.Get);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            return response;
        }
```

I have read about the `Azure SDK for .net` and tried to use the `Azure.ResourceManager` package but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I used below c# code and got access token with list of subscriptions successfully in **response** like this:

```cs
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace AzureRestApiListSub
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Azure AD application details
            string clientId = "bb2c371a-d0f8-492c-9252-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
            string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            string tenantId = "2f6e32f4-8752-4f56-9154-xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

            // Azure REST API endpoint
            string apiVersion = "2020-01-01";
            string endpoint = $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version={apiVersion}";

            {
                // Set up the authentication context
                var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                    .Create(clientId)
                    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                    .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}"))
                    .Build();

                string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" };

                // Authenticate and acquire an access token
                var authResult = await confidentialClientApplication
                    .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

                string accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
                Console.WriteLine(accessToken);
                Console.WriteLine();

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2021-01-01");
                string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.Write(json);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I used the above **access token** in Postman and got same results like below:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: I marked your post as the answer however check out my answer in which I use the Azure sdk to get same output

Answer (score 0):

While the previous answer is completely right and fine, I solved my problem by using the `Azure SDK for .Net`.
With that I am able to retrieve all information I'm getting when calling the Azure REST API using postman.
Now I can use the dot notation and resource Objects to access its attributes.

Here is an example code of how to get the subscriptionID as well as other resources like the virtual machines inside resource groups.

```
public string GetSubscriptionID(string tenantID)
    {
        var _config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
        // Create a token credential using the client ID, client secret, and tenant ID
        var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantID, _config["Azure:vm-executer:client_id"], _config["Azure:vm-executer:client_secret"]);
        // Create an ArmClient with the credential
        var client = new ArmClient(credential);
        return client.GetDefaultSubscription().Data.SubscriptionId;
    }

    public List<VirtualMachine> GetVirtualMachines(string tenantID)
    {
        var _config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
        // Create a token credential using the client ID, client secret, and tenant ID
        var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantID, _config["Azure:vm-executer:client_id"], _config["Azure:vm-executer:client_secret"]);
        // Create an ArmClient with the credential
        var client = new ArmClient(credential);

        // Get the list of subscriptions
        ResourceGroupCollection resourceGroups = client.GetDefaultSubscription().GetResourceGroups();
        List<VirtualMachine> vmList = new List<VirtualMachine>();

        foreach (ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup in resourceGroups)
        {
            VirtualMachineCollection virtualMachineCollection = resourceGroup.GetVirtualMachines();

            foreach (VirtualMachineResource vmResource in virtualMachineCollection)
            {
                VirtualMachine searchedVM = new VirtualMachine();
                searchedVM.ID = vmResource.Data.VmId;
                searchedVM.Name = vmResource.Data.Name;
                searchedVM.Status = "tbd";

                foreach (InstanceViewStatus vmStatus in vmResource.InstanceView().Value.Statuses)
                {
                    if (vmStatus.Code.Equals("PowerState/running"))
                    {
                        searchedVM.Status = "Running";

                    }
                    if (vmStatus.Code.Equals("PowerState/deallocated"))
                    {
                        searchedVM.Status = "Deallocated";

                    }
                }

                vmList.Add(searchedVM);
            }
        }

        return vmList;
    }
```